# uitableview.backgroundView image dimension is compressing/distorting

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I'm building an iphone app.

I have a tableview and i set a background image like so:

```
UIImageView * bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:somebackgroundimage];
CGRect framebg = bg.frame;
framebg.origin.y = -64;
framebg.origin.x = 0;
framebg.size.width = 320;
framebg.size.height = 480;
[bg setFrame:framebg];
[_tblview setBackgroundView:bg];
```

no matter what framebg.size.width or framebg.size.height I set, the image always appears distorted or compressed with a size of maybe 320 width and 400 height.  It is almost as if the app will forcefully resize the image to fit between the top navigation bar and my bottom tab bar.

How do I force tableview background image to be of 320px width by 480px height?

Also it seems the origin.y and origin.x aren't being respected either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but I thought i would share what I was able to use to get around a similar issue (using `setContentMode` for the image view):

```
UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bg;
```

Hope this helps.